# callback function argument in javascript / jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to go through a book to learn jQuery ui. I run into this code

```
 $("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
     minLength: 2,
     source: function (request, response) {
         $.getJSON("https//api.github.com/search/repositories", {
             q: request.term + " in:name"
         })
             .then(function (data) {
             var matches = $.map(data.items, function (repo) {
                 return repo.full_name;
             });
             response(matches);
         });
     }
 });
```

In the .then(function(data){}), is the data object passed by the result of $.getJSON() function? I checked jQuery API. I think in this case I am dealing with doneFilter callback but the API didn't mention any default object that is passed in the function. Can anyone explain more about this behavior? And why the data object contains a items property?

Comment: `data` is `JSON response` which you get when request to your server gets resolved

Comment: .items is the property defined on `data` object

Comment: Why don't you just use the `success` callback of [`.getJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)?

Comment: Hi, Kalam Sir, thanks for reply. So the data object is always there? like event object?

Comment: data is what your server returns

Comment: hi, Timo. this is a example from jquery ui book

Comment: `$.getJSON ({})` returns deferred object and `.then` is adds an handler which gets called when the Deferred object is resolved, rejected, or still in progress.

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/

Comment: Provide full URL inculing query string, that you are trying to fetch the data from?

Comment: Kalam Sir, I get that. I just want to learn more of the data object. For example, what properties it have, in what situation I can use it. Any document of it? I know it may sounds silly but I am beginner to jQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are dealing with a promise object.
As of jQuery 1.5, all of jQuery's Ajax methods return a superset of the XMLHTTPRequest object. This jQuery XHR object, or "jqXHR," returned by $.getJSON() implements the Promise interface, giving it all the properties, methods, and behavior of a Promise.

so .then() will get called after the completion of async call and it will use the success response object in data as an input.

**FOR MORE DETAILS ON PROMISE**

http://davidwalsh.name/write-javascript-promises